# QGIS create layer from spreadsheet file (Spreadsheet Layer plugin)

Tags: qgis, spreadsheet

With the QGIS plugin 'Speadsheet Layers' i try to create a layer with the following parameters:

[image]

But I'm just getting a layer with no geometry. I've been playing arround with real instead of integers, as well as removing lines containing no coordinates, but no effect.

Did anyone make it to get a point layer out of a spreadsheet? What am I probably missing?

Comment: Perhaps a QGIS version issue? This works for me using QGIS 2.14.3-Essen for Win 64-bit.

Comment: I fear not. I tried this with 2.14.3 and 2.8.9LTR... It's just too hot in my office for me and my brain to imagine other reasons :-(

Comment: Could you upload your spreadsheet (or a sample of it) onto a public server so that others could test it?

Comment: Not so easily - data protection... But I think it has something to do with formatting, I'll test this and then post it as an answer.

Comment: Looks like your coordinates are in metres not decimal degrees hence the issue you are having.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this issue is comparitively simple. Cp. Screehshot for an idea of the spreadsheet I had to process.

[image]

These beautiful colored, linebreaked nicely human readable spreadsheets are an invention of satan himself. This Spreadsheet was so full of formatting, blanks, special characters and linebreaks in column headers, cross references,... that a successful import would have been really suprising.

Replacing all colum headers (e.g. `Haus- nummer` > `hnr`) solved my problem.

Just to sum up the problem:

[image]

Comment: Ha! Wish I could give another +1 for your image =)

Comment: Just a remark, Gauss-Krueger X values are Longitudes, not Latitudes. I usually make a CSV export and add it as delimited text.

Comment: Good point, and true. I'll hand this off to the provider of this piece of great spreadsheet art.